# Undefined symbol for architecture i386 on linking SWIG C++ Wrapper Object for Ruby compiled with -m32 option

Tags: c++, ruby, macos, swig, 32-bit

Greetings StackOverflow Community,

I've got a SWIG project that generates a Ruby C API wrapper for a C++ static archive library. I don't have any problems generating and compiling the code under 64-bit Linux (tested under Fedora and Debian). Unfortunately, the OS X version of the archive is 32-bit only. I've built a 32 bit version of Ruby on OS X in order to generate, compile, and link the shared object that will be used as the Ruby C Native Extension:

```
$ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i386-darwin11]
```

All objects are compiled with the *-m32* flag:

```
$ g++ -m32 -Wall -g -c -fPIC -rdynamic ../src/CPPExampleWrapper.cpp ../src/CPPExampleException.cpp ../src/CPPExampleObject.cpp ../src/CPPExampleCallbackFunctor.cpp -I../include/ -I../lib/include/
```

and linked accordingly:

```
g++ -m32 -shared -fPIC -o ../lib/cppexample.so ./bin/CPPExampleWrapper.o ../qa_cpp_utils/bin/CPPExampleObject.o ../qa_cpp_utils/bin/CPPExampleCallbackFunctor.o ../qa_cpp_utils/lib/libcppexamplearchive.a -framework CoreFoundation -lpthread
```

On linking, I receive an error indicating that symbols referenced in CPPExampleWrapper.o are undefined for architecture i386:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_rb_big2long", referenced from:
      SWIG_AUX_NUM2LONG(unsigned long*)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_big2ulong", referenced from:
      SWIG_AUX_NUM2ULONG(unsigned long*)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_cFalseClass", referenced from:
      _rb_class_of in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_cFixnum", referenced from:
      _rb_class_of in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_cNilClass", referenced from:
      _rb_class_of in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_cObject", referenced from:
      _Init_CPPExample in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_Ruby_SetModule in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_Ruby_define_class in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_cSymbol", referenced from:
      _rb_class_of in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_cTrueClass", referenced from:
      _rb_class_of in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_check_type", referenced from:
      _SWIG_Ruby_GetModule in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_Ruby_ConvertPtrAndOwn in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_const_get", referenced from:
      _SWIG_Ruby_NewPointerObj in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_data_object_alloc", referenced from:
      _SWIG_Ruby_SetModule in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_Ruby_NewClassInstance in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_Ruby_NewPointerObj in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_define_alloc_func", referenced from:
      _Init_CPPExample in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_define_class", referenced from:
      getNullReferenceError()      in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      getObjectPreviouslyDeletedError()      in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_Ruby_SetModule in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_define_class_under", referenced from:
      _Init_CPPExample in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_Ruby_define_class in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_define_const", referenced from:
      _Init_CPPExample in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_define_method", referenced from:
      _Init_CPPExample in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_define_module", referenced from:
      _Init_CPPExample in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_Ruby_InitRuntime in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_define_module_function", referenced from:
      _Init_CPPExample in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_define_readonly_variable", referenced from:
      _SWIG_Ruby_SetModule in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_define_singleton_method", referenced from:
      _Init_CPPExample in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_eArgError", referenced from:
      SWIG_Ruby_ErrorType(int)   in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _wrap_new_JobOrder(int, unsigned long*, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _wrap_JobOrder_src_location_set(int, unsigned long*, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _wrap_JobOrder_src_location_get(int, unsigned long*, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _wrap_JobOrder_dst_location_set(int, unsigned long*, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _wrap_JobOrder_dst_location_get(int, unsigned long*, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _wrap_JobOrder_xfer_params_set(int, unsigned long*, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      ...
  "_rb_eFatal", referenced from:
      SWIG_Ruby_ErrorType(int)   in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_eIOError", referenced from:
      SWIG_Ruby_ErrorType(int)   in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_eIndexError", referenced from:
      SWIG_Ruby_ErrorType(int)   in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_eNoMemError", referenced from:
      SWIG_Ruby_ErrorType(int)   in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_eRangeError", referenced from:
      SWIG_Ruby_ErrorType(int)   in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_eRuntimeError", referenced from:
      getNullReferenceError()      in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      getObjectPreviouslyDeletedError()      in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      SWIG_Ruby_ErrorType(int)   in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_eSyntaxError", referenced from:
      SWIG_Ruby_ErrorType(int)   in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_eTypeError", referenced from:
      SWIG_Ruby_ErrorType(int)   in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_eZeroDivError", referenced from:
      SWIG_Ruby_ErrorType(int)   in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_funcall", referenced from:
      _SWIG_RubyRemoveTracking in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_gv_get", referenced from:
      _SWIG_Ruby_GetModule in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_RubyInitializeTrackings in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_gv_set", referenced from:
      _SWIG_Ruby_GetModule in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_RubyInitializeTrackings in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_hash_aref", referenced from:
      _SWIG_RubyInstanceFor in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_hash_aset", referenced from:
      _SWIG_RubyAddTracking in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_hash_new", referenced from:
      _SWIG_RubyInitializeTrackings in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_inspect", referenced from:
      Ruby_Format_TypeError(char const*, char const*, char const*, int, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_int2big", referenced from:
      _SWIG_RubyPtrToReference in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_RubyObjectToReference in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      SWIG_From_int(int)   in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_intern", referenced from:
      _SWIG_Ruby_InitRuntime in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_RubyInitializeTrackings in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_Ruby_NewPointerObj in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_iv_get", referenced from:
      _SWIG_Ruby_NewPointerObj in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_Ruby_MangleStr in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_iv_set", referenced from:
      _SWIG_Ruby_NewClassInstance in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_Ruby_NewPointerObj in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_ivar_get", referenced from:
      _SWIG_RubyInitializeTrackings in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_ivar_set", referenced from:
      _SWIG_RubyInitializeTrackings in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_num2long", referenced from:
      _SWIG_RubyReferenceToObject in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      SWIG_AUX_NUM2LONG(unsigned long*)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_num2ulong", referenced from:
      SWIG_AUX_NUM2ULONG(unsigned long*)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_obj_classname", referenced from:
      Ruby_Format_TypeError(char const*, char const*, char const*, int, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_obj_is_kind_of", referenced from:
      _SWIG_Ruby_ConvertPtrAndOwn in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_raise", referenced from:
      _wrap_new_JobOrder(int, unsigned long*, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _wrap_JobOrder_src_location_set(int, unsigned long*, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _wrap_JobOrder_src_location_get(int, unsigned long*, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _wrap_JobOrder_dst_location_set(int, unsigned long*, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _wrap_JobOrder_dst_location_get(int, unsigned long*, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _wrap_JobOrder_xfer_params_set(int, unsigned long*, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _wrap_JobOrder_xfer_params_get(int, unsigned long*, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      ...
  "_rb_rescue", referenced from:
      SWIG_AsVal_unsigned_SS_long(unsigned long, unsigned long*)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      SWIG_AsVal_long(unsigned long, long*)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_str_append", referenced from:
      Ruby_Format_TypeError(char const*, char const*, char const*, int, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_str_cat", referenced from:
      Ruby_Format_TypeError(char const*, char const*, char const*, int, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_str_cat2", referenced from:
      Ruby_Format_TypeError(char const*, char const*, char const*, int, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_str_new", referenced from:
      SWIG_FromCharPtrAndSize(char const*, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      Ruby_Format_TypeError(char const*, char const*, char const*, int, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_str_new_cstr", referenced from:
      _SWIG_Ruby_NewClassInstance in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_Ruby_NewPointerObj in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      Ruby_Format_TypeError(char const*, char const*, char const*, int, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_string_value_ptr", referenced from:
      _wrap_XferParams_exclude_patterns_set(int, unsigned long*, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _wrap_CPPTransfer_SetExcludePattern(int, unsigned long*, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      _SWIG_Ruby_MangleStr in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      SWIG_AsCharPtrAndSize(unsigned long, char**, unsigned long*, int*)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
      Ruby_Format_TypeError(char const*, char const*, char const*, int, unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_uint2big", referenced from:
      SWIG_From_unsigned_SS_long(unsigned long)in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_undef_alloc_func", referenced from:
      _Init_CPPExample in CPPExampleWrapper.o
  "_rb_undef_method", referenced from:
      _SWIG_Ruby_define_class in CPPExampleWrapper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Perhaps not so coincidentally, all of the undefined symbols are members of the Ruby C API. Am I missing something at compile- or link-time? Alternately, perhaps there is something wrong with the 32-bit OS X build of Ruby created to facilitate generation of this extension?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it turns out that the problem was that Xcode had installed a 64-bit version of Ruby and put it on the system path. In order to resolve the issue, I had to explicitly specify the path to the 32-bit version of the Ruby binary on the link line:

```
g++ -arch i386 -shared -fPIC -o ../lib/cppexample.so ./bin/CPPExampleWrapper.o ../qa_cpp_utils/bin/CPPExampleObject.o ../qa_cpp_utils/bin/CPPExampleCallbackFunctor.o ../qa_cpp_utils/lib/libcppexamplearchive.a -L/PATH/TO/32BIT/RUBY -framework CoreFoundation -lpthread
```

This was not a problem in Linux, because the version of Ruby on the system path was built for the architecture being linked.

James